# Assign Variables from Split

Tags: vb.net, split

Okay, so I have this string, it's "x/y". How can I use the split function to rid the / and assign the x to myVariable and assign the y to myVariable2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dim MyVariable as string = xystring.split("/")(0)
dim MyVariable2 as string = xystring.split("/")(1)
```